# How to select several slides using For Loop?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, slide

I have a presentation to split into several smaller ones depending on the text in the header.

I've managed to find and compile a code that finds the last slide that has the text), then it selects several previous slides, copies them to a new presentation, saves it, and repeats that for the next value.

This would be fine if number of slides with every text was the same (and all the slides with the same text were in the same order), but it's not always the case in my presentation. I need to modify the function.

Basically, it should return not just a slide, but a slide range, and it should be resized with every loop where if function is true. I know how to get all the slide indexes as a string, but I don't know how to use that string to select those slides.

```
Function FindSlideByTitle(sTextToFind As String) As slide

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.slides
    With oSl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame
        If .HasText Then
            If InStr(1, .TextRange.Text, sTextToFind, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Set FindSlideByTitle = oSl
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an advantage to creating a slide range in this instance. A function for this isn't going to work, since it can only return one slide at a time, as you've discovered.

Instead, create a Sub using your loop, then replace

```
Set FindSlideByTitle = oSl
```

with a routine to add the found slide to an array:

```
Option Base 1
Dim FoundSlide() As Integer
Dim oSl As Slide

Sub FindSlideByTitle()
  ReDim Preserve FoundSlide(1)
  For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    With oSl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame
      If .HasText Then
        If InStr(1, .TextRange.Text, "Ham", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
          Count% = UBound(FoundSlide)
          ReDim Preserve FoundSlide(Count% + 1)
          FoundSlide(Count% + 1) = oSl.SlideNumber
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Then process that subset of slides one at a time:

```
Sub DoSomethingWithSlide()
  For X = 1 To UBound(FoundSlide)
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(FoundSlide(X))
      'Process each slide here
    End With
  Next X
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  This could be a good solution, but the idea was to find all slides containing a certain text, select them, and then copy all selected slides to a new presentation, and then save it as a new file.  I already had a piece of code to create a new presentation from selected slides with the same formatting, but with your approach I'd have to redo it - because the action would have to be different for the first slide and for all consecutive slides...

Comment: I answered your question as you asked it. Revealing new  requirements later doesn't invalidate my answer. I would appeciate an upvote, so others can find how to solve similar issues.

Comment: I never said your answer was invalid, I said it would work in another circumstances.  And to be fair, I did mention it from the start that the end goal is to copy selected slides to a new presentation (which is not the same task as to copy slides on by one).  I did upvote your answer, but, apparently, my reputation is not high enough for the upvote to be publicly visible - I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, this is what I came up with in the end, and it (almost) seems to be working.

```
Dim sSlides() As String
    sSlides() = Split(FindSlide(sCountry), ";|;")

Dim n As Long
Dim iSlides() As Integer
ReDim iSlides(LBound(sSlides) To UBound(sSlides))
For n = LBound(sSlides) To UBound(sSlides)
    iSlides(n) = CInt(sSlides(n))
Next n

Dim rCountrySlides As SlideRange
Set rCountrySlides = ActivePresentation.slides.range(iSlides)
rCountrySlides.Select
```